# Get programs and their members and status with Marketo API

Tags: marketo

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a list of active programs (specifically 'event' types), and then list the members of those programs and their current status within them.

Basically, I'm looking to replicate the Members tab on the top level of the Program view in order to have an external view of our event processes, but add extra functionality to enable non-marketo users to change statuses of those leads (ie from Registered -> Attended).

From what i can see, this isn't possible with the REST API at the moment (?), and I can't quite get my head around what calls to use in the SOAP API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few different topics in your question, so I'll talk about them individually.

- Is it possible to get a list of active programs? This is possible. You can get a list campaigns and their associated programs through the [Get Multiple Campaigns REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-campaigns/).
- Is it possible to get a list program members? This is possible. You can get a list of leads associated with a Program through the [Get Multiple Leads by Program Id REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-program-id/).
- Is it possible to a get a lead's status in a program? This is not directly possible, but there is a workaround. When a lead's status changes in a program, you can add that lead to a static list. You can then query leads from that static list using the [Get Multiple Leads by List Id REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-list-id/).

Comment: Thanks Murtza - I'll have a play with those API calls, though I'm not sure i can get exactly what i need from them..

Comment: Actually, looking at it from a different angle, if i have those leads in static lists according to status, maybe I would be better to use Get Multiple Lists filtered by the list names, then break those results up by program name... I'll try and remember to report back what i end up doing!

Comment: Hmm, _Get Multiple Leads by Program Id_ looks like it would suit me even better, as it includes progressionStatus... but is there no way to return a list of Program Ids through the REST API in the first instance?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not currently possible to get a list of Program Ids via the REST API. As Jep mentioned, you can get a list of Programs from the SOAP API using the getMObjects endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of Programs, use the SOAP API  getMObjects with type = Program: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/getmobjects/